# Get pixel coordinates using mouse in cv2 video frame with python

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to get the pixel coordinate using the mouse in a video live-feed frame with CV2 and python.

The following is my code:

```
import cv2      # import the OpenCV library                     
import numpy as np  # import the numpy library

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

def mouseHandler(event, x, y, flags, params):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        print(x, y)
        cv2.circle(frame, (x, y), 3, (255, 0, 0), -1)


cv2.setMouseCallback('Video', mouseHandler)


while(True):

    # Capture frame-by-frame
    _, frame = video_capture.read()

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But when I run, the frame with the live video appears but no response from left mouse key (or any other key).

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: @nathancy Yeah, I guess what OP's missing here is the `cv2.namedWindow` before setting the callback.

Comment: Yep, I was missing the cv2.namedWindow part.
Thank you very much.